# how to know wether predictive text is enabled in android

Tags: android, text, android-edittext, prediction

How to know whether  predictive text is Enabled/Disabled? In the code i need to know whether predictive text is enabled. I tried to disable the suggestions in `EditText` i have tried

```
android:inputType="textVisiblePassword|textfilter|textNoSuggestions"
```

but it doesn't work for me. this is why i want to know if predictive text is enabled or not.

Comment: I am not aware that input method editors (a.k.a., soft keyboards) have access to any system-wide setting regarding predictive text, let alone have to honor it.

Comment: i am sorry but i am not very good in english i can't understand what u are saying